# What's a good way to format this?

Tags: python, printing, format

Here's the code:

```
print "Unsorted \t Bubble \t Insertion"

for x, y, z in zip(List, arr_bs, arr_is):
    print '{0:2d}\t\t{1:3d}\t\t{2:4d}'.format(x, y, z)

print "Seconds: \t %f \t %f" % (time_bs, time_is)
```

Here's the output:

```
Unsorted     Bubble      Insertion
43        5        5
88       18       18
57       24       24
86       37       37
81       37       37
18       38       38
 5       43       43
24       57       57
76       76       76
37       81       81
37       86       86
38       88       88
Seconds:     0.000091    0.000042
```

Ah, couldn't get the output to look exactly like it does in terminal, but you get the idea.
I'm pretty new to python, is there a more pythonic way of formatting these print statements?

Open to opinions, thanks.

Comment: How do you want that to be printed?

Comment: Well, the way it's printed now is fine for me. But I was just wondering if there were more elegant looking solutions.

Comment: Perhaps a better title for this question could make it more searchable in the future?

Comment: It's kinda weird that you used `.format` for one line and `%` for another. Usually people stick to one or the other.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
print "%-25s %-15s %15s" % ("STACK","OVERFLOW","PYTHON")
```

Above line of print can be used in your code. You just need to substitute the string constant with your variables.